# Excel Add-In deployment problem

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto, excel-2007

I built an Excel add-in with VSTO 2005 SE, which I deployed to a user base that is predominantly Office 2003-based, but also with several workstations that have Office 2007 installed on them.

On the Office 2003-based workstations, the add-in works perfectly.

Now because this add-in was created with the version of VSTO for Office 2003, the add-in does not have a ribbon, and should show up under the add-ins tab when Excel 2007 is opened.

However, on the Office 2007-based machines, the add-in fails to show up.  When I check the registry under the `[HKLM\Microsoft\Office\Excel\AddIns]` key, the `LoadBehavior` is set to 0, which I believe indicates that the AddInLoader.dll failed to even start (got deactivated).  Strangely, when I changed all the keys to `HKCU` and not `HKLM`, the add-in magically started to show up and work.

Does anyone know if the Excel 2007 has a restriction on the registry keys to `HKCU` only?  If someone can help bring some insight, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx):

> By default, applications in the 2007
>   Microsoft Office system can only load
>   add-ins that are registered under
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER. To load add-ins
>   that are registered under
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, computers that
>   have these applications installed must
>   also have hotfix package 976477
>   installed. For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=184923.